# multi-factor authentication for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Does anyone have any pointers for implementing the following:

I want to cheaply enable multi-factor authentication on an asp.net website. I want people to be able to use an app on their phone (iPhone at the very least) to generate the token used alongside their username/password to login to the site.

I do not want the people to have to carry a third-party device/fob to generate the token.

thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved my problem by making use of the [Google Authenticator](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=1037451) and a slight modification of this: http://code.google.com/p/g-authenticator-wp7/

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

- Each client gets a copy of a public key
- Each client gets a random GUID that it will be identified with
- A custom code that generates a token based on time (up to minute), IP Address (possibly) and the GUID using the key.

When clients install the app for the first time, GUID is created and is then encrypted by the key and sent to the server as part of registration of the product.

Then on, for using the site, a token is generated and encrypted by the key and sent to the server. Server disassembles the token and identifies the GUID and matches the time and IP address (possibly).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple factors simply mean more than one way to verify a user's identity.  The username/login id is the identifier, so we need to make sure that the identifier is really coming from the person it is assigned to.

The most common (and most frustrating) verification method is the password.  It's a secret that supposedly only the user knows.

Other forms of verification include:

- Mac address/machine identifier (if it comes from a known source, it's probably them--unfortunately easily spoofed as well).
- PKI--key management is the only thing that makes this more secure than a password.  Essentially the onus is on you to verify that the certificate request they submit from their device is truly them.  Once you do, you issue the certificate that they use from that point forward.  NOTE: not all browsers support PKI (this is a noticeable lack in Google Chrome at the moment).
- Secondary shared secret.  This can be GUID that is exchanged over an encrypted connection, or something like that.
- Biometrics.  Requires external equipment, but fingerprints and retina scans can be difficult to replicate.
- Mutating key from external service.  Something like an RSA fob that displays a new six digit key every minute.  The combination of the fob's serial number and the displayed key ensure you have the right guy.

NOTE: the RSA fob is an external device, but one you issue and does not require connection to the client machine.  Once you've linked the fob's serial number to the account, you use the user supplied six digit key on RSA's authentication service.  Of course, you server's time needs to be synchronized with RSA's.  Many corporate VPNs use this as the secondary (or sometimes primary) user verification method.

I'm sure there are many other options out there.  The trick is finding the right balance between the security you require and the maintenance headache when either verification method fails and the user calls for support.